# Python MySQLdb error - not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-3.6

I am working on a simple program that needs a connection in MySQL. I got a problem with my query and i'm stuck with it. It says that "not all arguments converted during string formatting" but as far as i know, my syntax is correct. What's the problem on it? Here is my code:

```
username = (self.username.text())
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", (username))
```

Comment: You meant to define query parameters as a tuple, you are missing a comma after "username":
`cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", (username, ))`

Comment: Oh thanks for the correction. I am just a beginner here btw. I thought that if it works, it is already done.

Answer (score 0):

After making a plenty of trials and errors. I already got it haha. Here it is:

```
username = (self.username.text())
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", (username, ))
```

Comment: No, string-formatting an SQL query is NOT a solution. This is **a)** dangerous (see [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) **b)** error-prone (check what if `username` contains a single quote?).

Comment: I already updated my answer. Thanks again